# How to visualize GPS coordinates on a map using Node red?

Tags: gps, ibm-cloud, node-red

I'm trying to track the location of an object/vehicle for this, I'm using a GY-GPS6MV2 module for getting GPS coordinates. I'm streaming those values to Bluemix - Internet of Things cloud platform and trying to visualize the data on maps from node red using the WorldMap node. But while doing so I couldn't map them on the OpenStreetMap.
I have gone through the documentation on WorldMap node. But couldn't get the insights which are useful for me. Can you please help in this context?

Link :[WorldMap NodeRed](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-web-worldmap)

[image: Part of my NodeRed flow]

[image: Output of Merge Node]

Comment: It would help to have a sample of your GPS data, and an export of the part of your flow that receives the data and sends it to the worldmap node...

Comment: Show us what you have already tried

Comment: I have attached the part of my node red flow where I get the Latitude and Longitude values published at every 120 seconds from my hardware to bluemix cloud. I'm accessing the data to NodeRed using the IBM iot node. I'm displaying those values on the node red dashboard too. When I try to send this data(Latitude and longitude) to WorlMap node it is not pointing the coordinates on the map. It is just taking the start coordinates values in worldmap node.

Comment: Edit the question to include the format of the message that comes out of the "Merging Co-Ordinates" join node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the worldmap node docs:

> **Usage**
>
> Plots "things" on a map. The map will be served from
>   {httpRoot}/worldmap
>
> The minimum msg.payload must contain name, lat and lon properties,
>   e.g.
>
> ```
> {name:"Joe", lat:51, lon:-1.05}
> ```
>
> name must be a unique identifier across the whole map. Repeated location updates to the same name move
>   the point.

At the moment your `msg.payload` is a string with lat, then 2 new lines and then the lon value. You need to build a `msg.payload` that matches what's in the doc. This is probably best done directly from the output of the `IBM IoT` node as it looks to already be a JSON object which will make it easier to extract the correct values.